# Why does Sheets/Excel allow entering in SUMing cells with string values but not strings themselves?

Tags: arrays, excel, google-sheets, syntax, range

I've noticed the following:

[image]

Basically, I can do:

```
=SUM(range)
```

When that includes a cell, and also the individual cells:

```
=SUM(cell1, cell2, ...)
```

But when I enter in the literal values it gives me an error if they're not all numeric:

```
=SUM(val1, val2, val3)
```

Why is this so?

Comment: It's by design, so you'd have to ask Microsoft. Open the *Function Arguments* dialog box for that function. You'll see at the bottom that it states "Logical values and text are ignored in cells, **included if typed as arguments**."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in google sheets, if you want to pass a text string as an argument you can do:

```
=SUM(10, 20, 30, N("Hello"))
```

[image]

some people tend to use this in their complex formulae (not just SUM) as notes

[image]